# Why division symbol ÷ inside switch statement is giving multi-character character constant warning? As much I know it's a Character

Tags: c, character-encoding, char, non-ascii-characters

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Compiler version gcc  6.3.0
int main()
{
  int alpha,beta;
  char syb;
  printf("Enter two value followed by operend\n");
  scanf("%d %c %d",&alpha,&syb,&beta);
  
  switch(syb){
    case '+' : 
      printf("%d",alpha+beta);
      break;
    case '-' :
      printf("%d",alpha-beta);
      break;
    case '*' :
      printf("%d",alpha*beta);
      break;
    case '÷' :
      printf("Unable to reach this case");
      break;         
  }
  return 0;
}
```

> main.c:22:10: warning: multi-character  character constant [->Wmultichar]
> case '÷' :
> ^~~~
> main.c:22:5: warning: case label value exceeds maximum value for type
> case '÷' :
> ^~~~

Comment: There isn't a 'divide' single character but `'/'`. There isn't a keytop like `'÷'` either, but there is `'/'`. I see you used the C symbol `'*'` for multiply, so go with the flow!

Comment: The division symbol you're using is a 2-byte utf-8 code.  It won't fit in a single 8-bit byte.

Comment: @Weather Vane Sir is there any predefined set of symbol in C language ,Which I do have to use only?..Cos I'm treating it as a character thought it will pass that case but it didn't.

Comment: Most systems use the ASCII set for single-byte characters.

Comment: @Tom Karzes Oh thats the main reason Thank you Sir, much Appreciated.

Comment: To be more precise about unicode and utf-8: The division sign has code point 0x00F7, meaning its value is greater than 127 – which is the maximum code point value that can be represented with a single byte. Be aware that any byte with most significant bit set is part of a multibyte sequence.